# can't select with xml id in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity

As you can see I have an `UpdatableView` in `xml` file with `updatable_view` id, but I can't select it via `findViewById`. The `id` somehow gets removed and I don't know why. I printed out the view hierarchy and this particular view doesn't have an id. the others have of course! 
what can be the problem? I've tried cleaning, rebuilding, regenerating R. nothing helps!
[image]

**UPDATE**
in my activity's `onCreate` I do this

```
    setContentView(R.layout.starter_activity);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
```

in `UpdatableView` class that extends `FrameLayout` I do this:

```
public UpdatableView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    inflate(context,R.layout.torob_updatable_layout,this);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
}
```

and `torob_updatable_layout.xml` is as simple as this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<com.rey.material.widget.ProgressView
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        style="@style/CircleProgressBar"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />
<com.rey.material.widget.Button
        android:id="@+id/retry"
        style="@style/Button"
        android:text="تلاش دوباره"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone"
        />
</merge>
```

Comment: Post your Java Code.

Comment: in onCreate try this code:
View v = inflate(context,R.layout.torob_updatable_layout,this);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, v);

Comment: But Where you find your `UpdatableView`in this code?

Comment: in the activity I have `@Bind(R.id.updatable_view) UpdatableView updatableView;` but doesn't work because there is no id named `updatable_view` very strange, very strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of perplexity I found that one of my `UpdatableView` constructors was like this:

```
public UpdatableView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, null, 0);
}
```

instead it should've been like this:

```
public UpdatableView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}
```

Jesus! Make sure to pass the `attrs` or you won't get an id with your view.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use like below.

```
UpdatableView updateView = (UpdatableView)findViewById(R.id.updatable_view);
```

Comment: I know! this returns null

Comment: I think in onCreate try this code: View v = inflate(context,R.layout.torob_updatable_layout,this); ButterKnife.bind(this, v);

Comment: For more detail you can check in: http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/
in session "NON-ACTIVITY BINDING"

Comment: i don't think the problem is from `ButterKnife` because `findViewById` returns null. I tried other ways of inflation as you mentioned one of them, still the same thing, that particular View doesn't have an id. @quangson91

Comment: Can you try: replace <merge> in layout with another Layout (Like FrameLayout, LinearLayout). @MohMah

Comment: I tried that, it just adds another `FrameLayout` as the `UpdatableView`'s child. still the problem persists. @quangson91